# React-native-contact updateContact is updating all phone numbers for 1 contact instead of a specific number

Tags: android, react-native

We have a mobile application written in React-Native and we used the module React-native-contact from this guide: https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts

The purpose of the app is to change the prefix of numbers from XXX to YYY.

The contacts is well populated and all is working fine. However, we want to update 1 specific number for a Contact but unfortunately it is updating all the numbers for this Contact. We are able to get the list of contacts found in the contact book via this code:

```
 handleUpdate = () => {
 //phoneContacts => all the contacts found in the address book
 //contactDetails => all the contacts that have the prefix number that needs to be replaced. 
 //prefixNumber => is the prefix number that user wants to replace.
 const { phoneContacts, contactDetails, prefixNumber } = this.state;
 var updated_select = 0;
 var record = null;

  Contacts.getAll( (err, contacts) => {

  _.forEach(contactDetails, (contactD) => {

    if (contactD[1] == true) {

      //where contactD[5] is the specific phone number
       var num = contactD[5];
       num = num.replace(prefixNumber, '010');

      _.forEach(contacts, (cont) => {
         if (cont.recordID === contactD[0])
            //finding the record to be updated in the Contact List
            record = cont;
       });

       //Replacing the record phone numbers with the updated one. 
       record.phoneNumbers[contactD[3]] = { label: contactD[4], number: num };

       //Updating the contacts as per the guide linked above
       Contacts.updateContact(record, (err) => {
         if (err) {
           _alert('error', 'Application error: Update unsuccessful.');
           return;
         }
       });
        ++updated_select;
       }

  });

  ToastAndroid.show(updated_select + ' rows have been updated', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
   this.handleSearchContacts();
   return;
 });
}
```

So as a concrete example. We are changing the prefix number from 555 to 010
If User X has

```
phoneNumbers: [
   {label: "work",number: "(555) 555-5555"},
   {label: "mobile",number: "(444) 444-4444"},
  ],
```

On update, the app is updating both numbers for User X to:

```
 phoneNumbers: [
       {label: "work",number: "(010) 555-5555"},
       {label: "work",number: "(010) 555-5555"},
      ],
```

We also tried pushing all the values including the updated record but all numbers were being updated.

During debugging, we verified the value of variable record and it is showing the contact with the all its details long with the specific phone number updated correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I checked it, it is working correctly, if I update the new phone number, can you check what is the value of the record before an update? Also if still the error persists, can you provide a minimal working example of your function instance so that I may be able to replicate it?

Comment: @PritishVaidya, I have updated the question with a working example of the function. Hope this helps. As info, the record value is coming with the right values before doing the update function.

Comment: Can you please provide a repo to reproduce this?

Comment: What's the data structure looks like for phoneContacts and contactDetails? I'd recommend you not hardcoding contactD index and use property name instead.